# How do I add a well formatted HTML signature to Gmail? P.S. Copy & paste doesn't work

Tags: html, email, formatting, gmail, signature

it seems crazy that this still isn't an option but is there an elegant workaround? I have tried copying and pasting into the Settings>Signature box but it ruins the formatting.

Many thanks!

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

Create a .html file with your HTML in it. View the file in a browser. Then select the entire page (COMMAND+A or CTRL+A) and copy.

Paste into the Gmail signature textarea.

Basically the trick is to copy&paste the rendered html rather than the raw HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Try following the steps on this video:
[add gmail hmtl looking signature](https://youtu.be/r5mQdHu-pIU)

Basic guide:

1. Open google docs
2. Create a new file
3. Add a table
4. Add logo and text
5. Format table with lines to 0 pts
6. Modify look and colour of text
7. Copy format and paste into gmail signature

Hope that helps someone

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned you can indeed just copy the rendered HTML in to the signature box in your GMail settings. To do this just:

1. Put your HTML in to new text file and give it a name like signature.html
2. Open the file in your browser
3. Select all of the content displayed in the browser (edit > select all)
4. Copy of all the selected content (edit > copy)
5. Open up the GMail settings and then paste in to the signature box (edit > paste)

I had a problem doing this on a mac and using Chrome as my browser because there are two ways to paste. The normal paste removes the formatting so **you have to use the paste option that does not 'match style'**. See the image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The gmail signature creator uses a WYSIWYG creator. There doesn't seem to be a way to use HTML markup, but since you can choose fonts, insert images, change text-alignment, etc, you simply create the signature as you would in a word processor like Microsoft Word and Google converts it to HTML for you.

Comment: There is a way to do it, you just paste the rendered HTML in to the input box.

Answer (score 0):

This can get you an approximation but it does not keep any advanced styles.

Div tags do not work, and you have to be using a supported font which greatly limits your options.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).